# Twitter Oauth Checking Friendship

Tags: twitter, oauth

Twitter oauth, when i use

```
$bune = $connection->get('friendships/exists', array('user_id_b' => $adaminid, 'user_id_a' => $friends["id"]));
```

my web site opening very slow, how can i check 2 users friendship faster ? is there another method for using twitter oauth ?

or how can i check, im following but the user doesnt following me back with php

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [GET friendships/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friendships/show) instead. It shows more in-depth details.

As a general rule you should perform actions asynchronously so users are not waiting for forever. Twitter is usually very good about their response times however so if it is taking more than a second something else is likely causing the slowdown.